# Elasticsearch, term suggester returns

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I can't make `term suggester` work.

Here are my setups.

```
'name_not_analyzed': {
    'type': 'string',
    "index": "not_analyzed"
},

'suggest': {
    'type': 'completion',
    'analyzer': "simple",
    'search_analyzer': 'simple',
    'payloads': 'yes'
}
```

And here are my requests.

** Term suggester doesn't work..

```
GET /reviewmeta_index/_suggest
{

    "my" : {
    "text" : "dd",
        "term" : {
        "field" : "name_not_analyzed"
         }
     }
}
```

** completion suggester works..

```
GET /reviewmeta_index/_suggest
{
  "product_suggest":{
        "text":"dd",
        "completion": {
            "field" : "suggest"
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation on how I should set up for term suggester to work is sparse..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Completion Suggester` is for Autocomplete feature so query like

```
{
  "name_suggest":{
        "text":"d",
        "completion": {
            "field" : "suggest"
        }
    }
}
```

will give you something like

```
    "options": [
                {
                   "text": "donald",
                   "score": 8
                },
                {
                   "text": "david",
                   "score": 7
                }
]
```

while `term suggester` is for spell checking and finding similar terms, so you need to query like

```
{
  "my-suggestion": {
    "text": "davi",
    "term": {
      "field": "name_not_analyzed",
       "size" : 10
    }
  }
}
```

which will give you something like this

```
"options": [
            {
               "text": "dave",
               "score": 0.8333333,
               "freq": 11
            },
            {
               "text": "david",
               "score": 0.6666666,
               "freq": 6
            }
     ]
```

I use term suggester for "Did you mean" feature when user gets zero results. More [options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html) for term suggester to tweak.

**EDIT 1: Added min_word_length option**

since your `text` is of only 2 characters and because default value of `max_edits` is 2 and default value of `min_word_length` is 4, you are not getting any results.

You need to add `min_word_length` option to your query

```
GET /reviewmeta_index/_suggest
{

    "my" : {
    "text" : "dd",
        "term" : {
        "field" : "name_not_analyzed",
        "min_word_length" : 2
         }
     }
}
```

The above query will give you suggestions like *"do","did"* but wont give you *"DO","Did"* as you have `index : not_analyzed` on the field.

**Note:** You can not increase `max_edits` to more than 2 which is default.

The [algorithm](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzziness.html) used by ES to calculate edit distance.

Comment: yeah, but term suggestion doesn't return anything (empty options). Is there a special setup work I need to do to make it work?

Comment: could you please provide some sample documents that you think should match for your term suggester query?

Comment: @eugene I have edited my answer. please let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks! `min_word_length` was the problem as you suggested.